# ASP.NET FormsAuthentication - Length of the data to decrypt is invalid

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, encryption, webforms

We're using the `FormsAuthentication` class to pass encrypted tokens between a Classic ASP system and a .NET system. We have a COM component (.NET 2) called by the Classic ASP system, and the same class used directly in .NET.

The code looks something like this (without the hard-coded values):

```
FormsAuthentication.Initialize();
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, "", new DateTime(2011, 1, 1), new DateTime(2012, 1, 1), false, "TEST");
var token = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
```

To decrypt, we do this:

```
var data = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt("E03519434CB6C157C24B5A1BFE3964537D9B0(SNIP)").UserData;
```

Both parts are currently running on the same server, however we have a machineKey set from when these systems were on different servers. Everything is running in .NET 3.5/CLR 2.

Recently we've been upgrading the .NET part of the system to .NET 4. Locally, the Classic ASP stuff runs on another server, so again, we've had the same machineKey set on our local machines (.NET) and the server running the Classic ASP stuff. The same machineKey is set in both 32+64 bit v2 machine.configs *and* both 32+64 bit v4 machine.config (note: we run IIS in 32 bit mode for some legacy COM components).

Locally, we've had no issues at all with the tokens being generated on the Classic ASP system (COM component, running in CLR 2) working on our local machines (.NET 4). However, when we just started to roll this out to the staging server, we're getting the following error:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Length of the data to decrypt is invalid.
at System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManagedTransform.TransformFinalBlock(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount)
at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()
at System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData(Boolean fEncrypt, Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length, Boolean useValidationSymAlgo, Boolean useLegacyMode, IVType ivType)
at System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(String encryptedTicket)
at NewMind.Tourism.DMS.Sso2.Sso.GetUserData(String dmsId, String token) in c:\CI\W\DMS-2.4-Release\NewMind.Tourism.DMS.Sso2\Sso.cs:line 131
at NewMind.Tourism.Core.Utils.SsoUtil.GetUserData(String token) in c:\CI\W\DMS-2.4-Release\NewMind.Tourism.Core\Utils\SsoUtil.cs:line 37
at NewMind.Tourism.Core.AuthenticationService.DoSsoLogin(String ssoToken, Action successAction, Action failureAction) in c:\CI\W\DMS-2.4-Release\NewMind.Tourism.Core\AuthenticationService.cs:line 126
```

I've spent all afternoon trying to track down the cause. I found a lot of articles talking about "aspnet:UseLegacyEncryption" which seems to fix the issue for many, however this doesn't seem to make any difference for us. I've created a small test script that tries to decrypt two tokens generated on my local machine (one in .NET 2, one in .NET 4), and run it in both CLRs on both machines:

- On my machine, CLR 2 ** Works **
- On my machine, CLR 4 ** Works **
- Stage sever, CLR 2 ** Works **
- Stage sever, CLR 4 ** Error **
- Stage sever, CLR 4, aspnet:UseLegacyEncryption=true ** Error **

I've run out of ideas. I'm not really sure what to try. The machineKeys are all identical, I've triple-checked. The UserLegacyEncryption option doesn't seem to make a difference. I can't compare tokens generated on each machine/CLR because they're different each time. We have no idea why the exact same code works on the exact same version of the .NET framework on our dev machines.

Our backup plans are to create a CLR 4 version of the COM component, or change the encryption entirely, but we'd really like to just understand the issue and be able to fix it.

Comment: The default hashing alogrithm was changed from SHA1 to SHA256 in ASP.NET 4.0. In your COM component, did you specify an explicit key but not specify the algorithm to use?

Comment: I can't see any way to specify this - the only code we have is what's in the top two code blocks above.

Comment: Are you sure the server is patched?

Comment: LOL! What sort of idiot wouldn't check server patches first? ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out we were missing a patch. The server was usually fully-patched, but since .NET 4 was only recently installed, and hadn't been patched afterwards, we were missing the patch that changed the encryption (due to an ASP.NET exploit).

Thanks to Damian Edwards + levib @ MS for their assistance!

Comment: There were many missing (.NET 4 was installed, but no patches for it ever installed at this point!), but the one causing the issue was this one, I think: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/18/important-asp-net-security-vulnerability.aspx